# How does the supplicant connect to the auth server in EAP TTLS?

Tags: authentication, 802.1x, wpa2-eap

I understand that a tls has to be established between the supplicant (end user device) and the auth server but a few things are unclear :

1. How does the supplicant know the ip adress of the auth server ?
2. The supplicant is not granted access yet it has to communicate with tls, does that mean it is granted a temporary local ip address and only requests to the auth server are forwarded via usual NAT by the access point ?
3. How does the supplicant authenticate the server ? If I were connecting to a website, I would chech the common name (and that the chain is correct up to a root CA certificate I have), but what would the supplicant check for in common name (subject) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Protocol stack

As explained in [section 5 of the draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-funk-eap-ttls-v1-01#section-5), the supplicant does not use TCP/IP for the TLS communication. The TLS communication is done over EAP.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| User Authentication Protocol (PAP, CHAP, MS-CHAP, etc.)|
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|          Inner Application extension to TLS            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                       TLS                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                     EAP-TTLS                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                       EAP                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Carrier Protocol (PPP, EAPOL, RADIUS, Diameter, etc.)  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

For WPA, the communication is done over EAPOL:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| User Authentication Protocol (PAP, CHAP, MS-CHAP, etc.)|
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|          Inner Application extension to TLS            |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                       TLS                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                     EAP-TTLS                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                       EAP                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                      EAPOL                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                       LLC                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                      Wifi                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice how there is no TCP/IP involved.

The Access Point is responsible to relaying the TLS communication to the TTLS authentication server.

The network stack would look like this:

```
[ CHAP     ]<---------------------->[ CHAP     ]
[ TLS      ]<---------------------->[ TLS      ]
[ EAP-TTLS ]<---------------------->[ EAP-TTLS ]
[ EAP      ]<---------------------->[ EAP      ]
                       [ RADIUS ]<->[ RADIUS   ]
                       [ TLS    ]<->[ TLS      ]
[ EAPOL    ]<->[ EAPOL | TCP    ]<->[ TCP      ]
[ LLC      ]<->[ LLC   | IP     ]<->[ IP       ]
[ Wifi     ]<->[ Wifi  | ...    ]<->[ ...       ]
 Supplicant     Access Point         RADIUS
                                     Server
```

Here is packet analysis for a **similar** method (EAP-TLS) by WireShark (see [PCAP file](https://github.com/vanhoefm/wifi-example-captures/blob/master/wireshark-wpa-eap-tls.pcap)):

[image: WireShark packet analysis]

### Authentication

On NetworkManager, the setup look like this:

[image: NetworkManager configuration]

In particular, you have to:

- configure the CA certificate used for authenticating the EAP-TTLS server;
- choose the domain name (or domain name suffix) of the EAP-TTLS server.

Comment: great answer, I assumed too early that tls has to be over ip.